Android 12 Settings Storage keeps crashing
Problem description & Background:
My phone suddenly stopped storing or retrieving files after I swapped the 64Gb SD for a bigger one - 1Tb.
I cannot access Settings/Storage to query, eject or reformat the SD. Files shows zero bytes in all categories except Apps, and I cannot download or update any apps.

I removed the 1TB SD and replaced the 64GB, and I have tried with no SD at all, but the damage was done.
Question: Can I get back to the "good" card? Or do I need to "Factory Reset?"

Your description may indicate that you bought a fake SD-card. While formatting not all sectors on the SD-card are tested, thus just formatting isn't sufficient to detect fake SD-cards. IMHO after buying a cheap SD-card it is strongly recommended to first test it e.g. by writing data to it until that card is at least 51% full (better 100%) and then checking the written files. Or use of the special sd-card test apps like True SD Card Capacity & Speed.

@DizzyGardener Hi, it seems you accidentally created a duplicate account. Please refer to the help center to merge your accounts and regain ownership of the question and reply to the comments on your post. Thanks for your understanding.
